# How to take different site collections to internet using different sub-domain

Tags: sharepoint-server

Our sharepoint farm will have a site collection that will host purely team and departmental content (sharepoint.company.com) and another site collection hosting project related content (project.company.com). Internally it's all taken care of, but I could not figure out how to get them out to the Internet especially in regards to the relationship between ports, IIS, and access mapping.

I tested using host file and reverse proxy sharepoint.company.com point to https://spwfe:443

The current site config is as follow:

- The external traffic will come in thru a reverse proxy. Both sharepoint.company.com and project.company.com are set to direct to the same sharepoint server internally.
- https://sharepoint.company.com is set to forward to https://spwfe:443

This is where i am a little confused. If one site collection already taken up port 443 on the sharepoint server, how would i go about setting up the second project site collection using SSL? The only way I could think of is to put it on a different port such as https://project.company.com:444 forwarding to https://spwfe:444, but i don't want user to have to type in the port number. I looked around on the web, and it seems like it's not recommended for reverse proxy to forward to different port (such as https://project.company.com to https://spwfe:444).

Can someone help shed some light on this? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Are both site collection in same web app or different? Are these host name site collection or path based?

Comment: Hi Waqas, thanks for the reply, i was able to talk to the infra. guys and was provided with information on basic web server 101. I think i was too fixated on port stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all starts with host headers. Same as port 80 traffic, host headers can also be leveraged on port 443. You'll need individual certs for each URL. I would start by reading this:
https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/ssl-host-headers-iis-8.htm

Comment: I'm glad I could help!